# How to enable menu item with a click of items of recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-menu, android-viewholder

I have a recycler view with checkboxes in **InterestsActivity** and I want to enable **NEXT button** on the toolbar after I got at least 4 checkboxes selected.

NEXT button is disabled in **onCreateOptionsMenu**(Menu menu)

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_interests_button, menu);
    nextBtn = menu.findItem(R.id.action_button);
    nextBtn.setEnabled(false);

    return true;
}
```

I have overridden **onPrepareOptionsMenu**(Menu menu) and trying to enable menu item there with a call to **invalidateOptionsMenu**() in onClick of my  ViewHolder item..

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_button);
    if(interestMap.size()>=4)
    item.setEnabled(true);

    return true;
}
```

My bind method in **ViewHolder**

```
public void bind(final Topic subject) {
        interestMap=new HashMap<>();
        mSubjectCheckbox.setText(subject.getSubjectName());
        mSubjectCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                interestMap.put(subject.getSubjectName(),true);
                if(interestMap.size()>=4)
                    InterestsActivity.this.invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }
        });
    }
```

But the button is not being enabled, am I doing right or missing anything?

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_button) {
        mFirebaseUtil.mFirestore.collection("users").document(FirebaseUtil.getCurrentUserId()).collection("interests").add(interestMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                Intent setupIntent = new Intent(InterestsActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                startActivity(setupIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Please help me resolve this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is not Enabled in which way? Is it visible?

Comment: @Gotiasits it is visible but disabled (not clickable).

Comment: In that case, share relevant part of your `onOptionsItemSelected()`

Comment: @Gotiasits updated with onOptionsItemSelected()

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with this code, unless its something trivial, like `interestMap.size()` never reaching size 4, or if menu item does gets clicked, but Firabase fails. Have you tried adding output to logcat in `onOptionsItemSelected()` for item in question?

Comment: @Gotiasits as you said it is reaching size 4 after selection of so many items and it is working unpredictable. when it is reaching 4 it is working fine. thanks

Comment: @Gotiasits it is working fine now, the problem is we are using hash map and interests are duplicated with dummy data, hash map is not allowing duplicates...thanks for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be nothing wrong with this code.

You should check if condition `interestMap.size()>=4` gets correct value, that is your `interestMap` is populated correctly.